# Error while inserting data to an enum generated field mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I am exporting data from one database on one server to another database on a different server. I am exporting to a csv file and using the import function on MYSQL workbench. Why am i using this way? That is because of access issues.

There is a field defined as,

```
`isTest` enum('TRUE','FALSE') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`Fixed` = _utf8mb4'FIXED') and ((`Type` is null) or (`Type` = _utf8mb4''))) then _utf8mb4'TRUE' else _utf8mb4'FALSE' end)) STORED,
```

The data in the exported file for this field looks like,

```
"FALSE"
```

The error is,

```
grt.DBError: ("The value specified for generated column 'isTest' in table 'Testing' is not allowed.", 3105)
```

Is there another way of inserting the data using workbench/editing the field column definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i excluded that field from the list of exports. The generated field will fill itself based on the data from the fields